# Java: Are all monitors released when thread waits on an object?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized

Before a thread can `wait` on an object, it has to acquire a monitor on that object. The monitor is then released, and the thread attempts to re-acquired it once it awakes.

But what happens to other monitors the thread holds when it calls `wait`?

Consider this example:

```
   Object a = // ...
   Object b = // ...

   synchronized(a)
   {
       synchronized(b)
       {
           b.wait();
           // continue
       }
   }
```

When the thread calls `b.wait()`, will it release the locks on *both* `a` and `b`, or only `b`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Only `b`.

The authoritarian source for these type of questions is the Java Language Specification. The relevant section in this case is [17.8 Wait Sets and Notification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#57537):

> Let thread *t* be the thread **executing the wait method on object *m***, and let *n* be the number of lock actions by *t* on *m* that have not been matched by unlock actions. One of the following actions occurs.
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, the following sequence occurs:
>
>   1. Thread *t* is added to the wait set of object *m*, and performs *n* unlock actions **on *m***.
>   2. [...]

Answer (score 11):

From the Java API documentation of the [Object class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29):

> The current thread must own this
>   object's monitor. The thread releases
>   ownership of **this monitor** and waits
>   until another thread notifies threads
>   waiting on this object's monitor to
>   wake up either through a call to the
>   notify method or the notifyAll method.
>   The thread then waits until it can
>   re-obtain ownership of the monitor and
>   resumes execution.

So, calling `b.wait()` releases the lock on `b` only.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK only b. It's a classic source of deadlocks.