# Java: wait(), notify() and nested synchronized blocks

Tags: java, multithreading

Will this work or result in deadlock?

thread 1:

```
synchronized (globalLock) {
  synchronized (o) {
    o.wait();
  }
}
```

thread 2 (later):

```
synchronized (globalLock) {
  synchronized (o) {
    o.notify();
  }
}
```

So from what I understand, o.wait() will release the lock of o, but will it release the lock of globalLock? Probably not and this will result in deadlock?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265330/java-are-all-monitors-released-when-thread-waits-on-an-object

Comment: *How* exactly would any method called on `o` have any effect on `globallock`?

Comment: @EJP, things that seem obvious to you are not always obvious to a noob.  Never the less, my sympathies align with Zielu's comment.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, this is trivially easy to test. Yes, it does deadlock for the reasons you guessed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  final Object globalLock = new Object();
  final Object o = new Object();

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      synchronized (globalLock) {
        synchronized (o) {
          try {
            System.out.println("waiting");
            o.wait();
          } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            // no-op
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }).start();

  Thread.sleep(2000); // ensure thread above starts first

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      synchronized (globalLock) {
        synchronized (o) {
          System.out.println("notifying");
          o.notify();
        }
      }
    }
  }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes deadlock when Thread 1 started before Thread2.
Thread 2 will never be able to execute its :

```
synchronized (globalLock)
```

because Thread 1 has never come out of `synchronized (globalLock)`

Comment: which would be deadlock precisely